# How to properly test a module that requires newrelic with jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, newrelic, jestjs

I'm working migrating a bunch of unit tests from mockery to jest. When I jest a module that requires the new relic agent like so: `require('newrelic')`, I get downstream errors like :

```
  - TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/newrelic/lib/config.js:165:33)
    at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-cli/src/Runtime/Runtime.js:261:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/newrelic/lib/logger.js:18:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/newrelic/index.js:3:14)
```

What is the best way to deal with modules like `newrelic` which jest has a hard time mocking? What have other people done when they have both jest and newrelic in their stack?

Answer (score 2):

The route I ended up taking was to create a mock module for newrelic in my `__mocks__` folder:

```
module.exports = {
    addCustomParameter: jest.fn()
};
```

I will probably need to add more functions later, but for now this is enough. I still wonder if there is a way to get jest to auto mock the newrelic library without erroring.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this with a few modules were automocking fails for various reasons, although it seems to happen a lot less frequently in the newer versions of Jest.

As @linuxdan suggests you might be able to work around the issue by using the manual mocking functionality documented [here](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/manual-mocks.html).

To so this you'll probably want to just export an object with the expected methods generated using `jest.fn()`.

The reason this will work is it will stop jest trying to determine the methods it needs to auto mock on the newrelic library. It will be during this process that it fails.